# Rules for a resisted alignment change?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alignment

As Pathfinder has quite a few special case rules, but I didn't find anything when I searched I'm wondering: Are there any (core or supplement) rules for an resisted permanent alignment change (either by number (good 3, good 2,...) or by value ("good, chaos",..))?

*Thus any rules on how an alignment change could be resisted (if induced non voluntarily by any means)*

Edit: As it was asked: I meant something like spells, supernatural abilities and template changes (although most spells have their own unique resistance as far as I'm aware).

Comment: I think this question would be much easier to tackle were it approached from the exact opposite direction: First explain what's causing this involuntary alignment change, *then* the site can propose measures to help resist that effect.

Comment: I agree. Some things, such as spells, have their own resist nature. Other things, like bad choices, may not. Not having examples of what what 'non voluntarily by any means' could be hampers us.

Comment: I hope my edit cleared it up.  I did not mean bad choices but "really" only involuntary things where the char had no real choice there but a resistance roll

Comment: I'm still getting an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) vibe from this question. I mean, I really want to know the exact reason for the change. Is the PC fearful of becoming accidentally on purpose the evil spawn of a [vampire](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/vampire/) when he'd rather remain the true neutral spawn of a vampire? Is there a terrorist organization that plants [*helms of opposite alignment*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/cursed-items/#TOC-Helm-of-Opposite-Alignment) on sleeping people's noggins? *Any* context would be great.

Answer (score 2):

When a character's alignment is changed by a spell, magic item or supernatural ability, the rules which describe that effect should mention if they allow a saving throw and what kind of saving throw. When no way to resist the change is explicitly mentioned, then there is no way to prevent it. The only way to "cure" your alignment change is finding some effect which changes your character's alignment in the opposite direction.

Different tables have different attitudes towards alignment. Some say that behavior affects alignment, others that alignment affects behavior. When your group belongs to the first category, you might be able to "fix" your new alignment by acting contrary to it. When your group belongs to the second kind, acting contrary to your new alignment might be considered bad roleplaying by the group, because your character is expected to act according to their new alignment.

Comment: So there are no general rules, but "situation specific" (aka a rule in each spell and ability that does it that CAN differ from the other rules there,...)a

Comment: @ThomasE. Yes..

Comment: You won't find any generic rules, really, since Alignment is a voluntary thing normally. So, involuntary changes are actually the opposite of the normal.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, effects that *shift* your alignment are clearly defined, like turning into a [vampire](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/vampire/) (no save), or holding a [cursed item](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/cursed-items/#TOC-Mace-of-Blood) (will save), or being [corrupted](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/corruption/) by some nightmarish unknown force (several different saves). The conditions of what *else* can alter a character's alignment are usually left to GM discretion.

The [Pathfinder Unchained](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9c25?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Pathfinder-Unchained) book gives us some (optional) [rules about alignment shifts](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/additional-rules/#Variant_Alignment_Rules_Unchained_Variant). Basically, each axis (lawful-chaotic and good-evil) get a **9-step progression** that goes from left (lawful and good) to right (chaotic and evil). Each action a character does that is strongly tied to an alignment will move the character one step into that direction, after 3 steps into a single direction (left or right), the character alignment has shifted.

I won't discuss the details or merits of these rules, you should read them and come to a conclusion by yourself if you will use these rules or not, as alignment is usually a sensitive topic and if you ask an alignment question to ten different people you will get ten different answers about it.